# building an unlock system with bluetooth and mobile phone using arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, mobile

I want to trigger the completion (connecting) of a circuit.

I want to do this via bluetooth on mobile phone. Setup:

1. User turns mobile app on
2. User puts phone near bluetooth reciever connected to arduino
3. Phone's app has code sent over signal that is used to authenticate
4. Arduino sends signal to electronically open door

I use a mac. I'd like to develop this.

Type of Arduino to buy? Correct bluetooth receiver? Software needed for all of this?

thanks for your help, I'm mostly a CS guy

Comment: If you are doing this for an iPhone it is not easy as you will have to be in the hardware dev program to access bluetooth serial comms. Perhaps WiFi instead? The question is pretty broad, maybe do some of your own research and come back with some specifics?

Comment: Perhaps a very simple RFID reader and a Nexus S phone with NFC?

Comment: This falls into the brainstorming and shopping category which are not a good fit for our Q&A format. Get a little bit of rep and then jump in the chatroom to ask brainstorming questions.

Answer (score 2):

Which bluetooth receiver? Like @user591124, I recommend you take a look a the [Arduino Bluetooth board](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBluetooth), which includes a BT receiver. If you wnat an external BT receiver, check out [search results at Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=bluetooth&what=products).

What software? To program your Arduino, you only need the Arduino software which you can [download from the Arduino site](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).

I believe the real issue here is actually going to be the electronic door lock. A quick Google search turned up the likes of [this site](http://www.sdcsecurity.com/category.aspx?id=6). They offer electromagnetic locks as well as control boards. It would then appear that you can hook up one of the Arduino outputs to a relay or transistor, which provide the control board with the correct voltage to lock/unlock the door.

Probably best to put the Arduino on the other side of the door, considering it would be quite easy to break in if you had access to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/arduinoBT

Try this looks apt for your project

You will need the arduino software for mac which is basically programmed in c. You will have to look into libraries that fit eachh part of the project